# No debuggable processes in android studio ؟؟؟

Tags: android, android-studio, adb

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u1NU5.png)

Hello friends.
As you can see in the picture, this section gives me this error, what is the cause and how to fix it?

Comment: you can select your application when it runs from the dropdown list]

Comment: but the list is emputy ??